# Compile .mm files in Eclipse CDT (os x)

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I have imported an xcode project into Eclipse CDT, which contains myfile.h and myfile.mm pairs. It seems, however, that *.mm files are ignored in the build, as I am getting "Undefined symbols" error for the classes implemented in the *.mm files.

How can I tell Eclipse CDT that for a given .h file it should compile .mm file too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, great question. Unfortunately the CDT currently doesn't have support for Objective-C files. There has been some discussion about that and hopefully we'll see more activity in the coming months. For now you would have to create your own Makefiles or use CMake to build from the xcodeproj file.